# Using OpenGL ES, how can I draw a flat ribbon (quad) in 3D space whose ends are always parallel to the viewing plane?

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, geometry, opengl-es-2.0, trigonometry

Ok, I'm sure that title was confusing, but what we're trying to do is actually pretty simple.  To explain the calculation, consider a cylinder drawn in 3D space given the two endpoints of its centerline and a diameter.  Now draw its silhouette against the plane of the screen, but square off the ends so they are parallel with each other and to the screen's plane.  That's the 'look' we need.

Now we could simply do exactly that... draw a cylinder with flat lighting to get this effect.  However, since we're not actually displaying the 3D shading, calculating all of the triangles that makes up the surface of the cylinder would be complete overkill.

Technically, all we need is a single quad, or at most, two triangles.  If the conceptual cylinder is parallel to the screen, then the result would just be a rectangle.  If the cylinder is angled towards or away from the screen, then the resulting silhouette is a simple trapezoid. Here's an example...

- A. Parallel to the screen, close
- B. Parallel to the screen, far
- C. Angled away from the screen, top-left (near) to bottom-right (far)
- D. Angled towards the screen, bottom-left (far) to top-right (near)

[image]

All we would like to do is basically specify the end points of the center line (red) in 3D space along with the 'width' of the ribbon.  But to do all of that, you need to not only take into consideration the endpoints in 3D space, but where the camera is too to determine how to make the ends parallel to the viewing plane as not to skew their width, and at that point, you may as well just go back to a cropped silhouette of a transformed cylinder!

So can anyone suggest a nice, simple way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. From the title it looks to me like you want something that will always display like examples A or B - what in C and D is parallel to the viewing plane?

Comment: The end lines (shorter two of the four... e.g. the ones the red lines touch) of all four shapes are parallel to the viewing plane (i.e. screen.)  Note that they are also perpendicular to the center (red) lines both in 3D space (world) as well as 2D space (screen) just as you see here. (Note these are hand-drawn so they may not show that perfectly but you should get the idea.)

Comment: What you are looking for is a kind of **billboarding**. I don't have the details myself, but [this tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/billboarding/) looks like it might include the answer (calling what you're looking for cylindrical billboarding). You might try some research with those keywords yourself.

Comment: Actually, the faces don't face towards the camera so it's not exactly the same, but I'll look into that tutorial to see if there's some info I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a rectangle with the length of the line and the width you desire and perform a 
[orthogonal projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection)

but that's me.

Or you could take any line from your plane (camera). And your line segment. These two can be used to form a new plane.  Then calculate the normal of this new plane.  This will be perpendicular to both your line and your plane.  I think that is what you're looking for.